# Cache Google maps for offline usage

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, caching, qwebview

I'm writing a Qt application which uses QWebView and [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps) to load streets of a town. I wonder if it's possible to cache Google maps for offline usage and if this violates Google's ToS or not. If there is no legal issues, how can I store maps in a manner that gmaps can load them instead of getting data from Google?

Our purpose is to provide pre-loaded data (streets of a small town) within application installation.

My browser (Google Chrome) seems to cache data. Because it loads previously loaded maps almost immediately. If re-distributing cached data violates ToS, I want to keep user's data (on his/her own machine).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of service, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can load maps of some cities when youre offline, Google maps have a special function in maps applications, depending on a place you need to show on map. This feature is located in Google maps Lab, there is a subApp called Download map area, ...turn it on and the go to maps, find a certain place in a few miles radius around, than click on it and in the bottom of menu, there is Download map area, and youre downloading. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Where is Download map area?

Comment: check out this video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSgcNTZ0afg)

Comment: That's for Android only. I'm writing a desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

[Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

10.1.3
(b) **No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content**. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.